Issues Adding Git LFS Repo as a Submodule: Not Appearing in .gitmodules
I'm trying to add a Git repository that uses Git LFS as a submodule in my project. When I run git submodule add <url_of_LFS_repo>, the command completes without errors, but the submodule doesn't appear in the .gitmodules file, and there are no changes listed in git status.
What could be causing the Git LFS repository not to be added as a submodule, and how can I resolve this?
EDIT: Extra information

First, I clone the repository where I intend to use submodules.
I add a submodule from a repository, which works fine and gets correctly added.
git submodule add https://github.com/vladimirzb/Cs.Computacion.git


Then, I add another submodule from a repo that uses Git LFS. It downloads the content, but it doesn’t get added as a submodule.
git submodule add https://github.com/vladimirzb/SecundariaORT.git



Video showing the problem:  https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/bd99e88f-a5b5-4807-9f1e-672b07cc4930
Here are the outputs from git lfs env:
~/D/G/Todos-Mis-Apuntes   ~…  git lfs env                           Wed 14 Aug 2024 03:53:12 AM -03
git-lfs/3.4.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.22.2)
git version 2.43.0

Endpoint=https://github.com/vladimirzb/Todos-Mis-Apuntes.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes
LocalGitDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes/.git
LocalMediaDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/home/vladi/Documents/GitHub/Todos-Mis-Apuntes/.git/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
GIT_ASKPASS=/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"

And here are the outputs from git config -l:
~/D/G/Todos-Mis-Apuntes   ~…  git config -l                         Wed 14 Aug 2024 03:53:14 AM -03
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=Vladimir Z.
user.email=****@users.noreply.github.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true

